# Remove drive partitions before Installing 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning

I have an old box and want to switch to Ubuntu 12.04.  It has two hard drives.  The first is a 40 gig disk that runs Windows XP; the other is 80 gigs partitioned into 40, 20, and 20 gigs.

I am prepared to abandon Windows altogether and everything stored on the drives.

So my question is, do I just install from CD/DVD onto the C drive?  Or onto one of the partitions in the other disk first and then uninstall Windows?  What will happen to the partitions on the second disk, which I don't particularly see a need for?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you won't use Windows then install Ubuntu on the 40Gig from DVD/USB. You can then use the 2nd drive to store your personal data - this will make it easier to upgrade. You can remove the partitions on it after you installed Ubuntu on the 40Gig by opening Disks from the dash.

If you want to keep Windows for just in case then just install Ubuntu on the 80Gig from a DVD/USB. The install should give you the option to clear the whole drive and install Ubuntu after you choose it as the drive to install Ubuntu to.

Answer (score 0):

1. For installing ubuntu alone no need to format your disk, just burn ubuntu iso image file into CD using imgburn.
2. Insert the CD and restart your computer. Normally computer will first look at the CD for boot file and ubuntu will start(If not keep pressing ESC/F2/F8/F12 while restarting depending on your computer and change the bios to boot from CD/DVD.).
3. Select "Try Ubuntu", if you like ubuntu click on install ubuntu on Harddrive.
4. If you want to install entire disk and wipe out windows and all files, then choose "Install ubuntu on the entire disk"